How do I get my Python Script to function correctly by changing output visualization of schedule by dynamically updating dropdowns
So the script below is suppose to open a GUI which it does, take a production schedule (part numbers, quantities, start and end dates) through upload button which it does, take the operational timings (through upload see image below) it needs for calculating a schedule which it does. Then the drop down menus on the GUI control page are populated with the constraints; shift length, number of operators, number of (essentially number of production lines) which the code is suppose to use in its calculation of the schedule. When the load and cap button (see image below) is clicked all the calculation runs and outputs the schedule onto a plot. It looks like when the constraints are set to 7.5 h shift length, with 1 operator and 1 plating vat the schedule is calculated correctly. See output plot below. I then have a few issues in terms of how the GUI is supposed to function which I cannot get it to do;

When the drop down values are changed this should be factored into the calculation of the schedule and update the schedule displayed on the plot. It does not do this the schedule stays formatted to the initial drop down values.
The plot is not correctly displaying the length of time for each part number. The bars representing the part numbers are the quantities, since the operational times for each part is the same I would expect the length of the total bar to be shorter as it takes less time than a quantity of 3 or 5 as can be seen with some of the part numbers in the display
The output summary text above the plot does not update correctly. I believe the first 7 fields populate correctly and dynamically with the changes to the drop down values (unlike the plot) but the last 3 earliest, actual and latest end dates do not change when the dropdown values are updated. These are supposed to show the earliest date in the uploaded operational plan, the latest date in the operation plan (that's our desired production delivery) and the actual is suppose to show the actual latest date after the calculation has run. That is then suppose to visually show me if the plan is achievable and how I need to modify the values in the drop down to get the production schedule within constraints.

This is the code and the GUI control page is below that.

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# Initialize global variables
operational_times = None
schedule = None

# Function to upload production file
def upload_production_file():
    global schedule
    file_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])
    if file_path:
        schedule = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        print("Production file loaded:", file_path)
        print("Columns in production file:", schedule.columns)

# Function to upload operational data file
def upload_operational_file():
    global operational_times
    file_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
    if file_path:
        operational_times = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=0)
        operational_times.columns = [col.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_') for col in operational_times.columns]
        print("Operational data file loaded:", file_path)
        print("Columns in operational data file:", operational_times.columns)

# Function to run load and cap calculations
def run_load_and_cap():
    if schedule is None or operational_times is None:
        print("Please upload both the production plan and operational data files.")
        return

    print("Running Load & Cap calculations...")
    print("Schedule data:")
    print(schedule.head())
    print("Operational times data:")
    print(operational_times.head())

    # Get dropdown values
    try:
        shift_length = float(shift_length_var.get())
        num_operators = int(operators_var.get())
        num_vats = int(plating_vats_var.get())
    except ValueError:
        print("Please select valid values for all dropdowns.")
        return

    # Print dropdown values for debugging
    print(f"Shift Length: {shift_length}")
    print(f"Number of Operators: {num_operators}")
    print(f"Number of Plating Vats: {num_vats}")

    # Calculate the multiplier based on shift length
    if shift_length == 7.5:
        multiplier = 1
    elif shift_length == 15:
        multiplier = 0.5
    elif shift_length == 22.5:
        multiplier = 0.3333
    else:
        print("Invalid shift length value.")
        return

    # Calculate total operations time
    total_batches = schedule['Number of batches required'].sum()
    total_operations = operational_times.iloc[:, 2:].sum().sum()
    total_shifts_required = (total_operations * multiplier) / (num_operators * num_vats)

    # Print calculated values for debugging
    print(f"Total Batches: {total_batches}")
    print(f"Total Operations Time: {total_operations}")
    print(f"Total Shifts Required: {total_shifts_required}")

    # Calculate the earliest start date and latest end date
    earliest_start_date = pd.to_datetime(schedule['Arrive in SF Date'], dayfirst=True).min()
    latest_end_date = pd.to_datetime(schedule['Delivery Date'], dayfirst=True).max()
    actual_end_date = earliest_start_date + pd.Timedelta(hours=total_shifts_required * shift_length)

    # Print date calculations for debugging
    print(f"Earliest Start Date: {earliest_start_date}")
    print(f"Latest End Date: {latest_end_date}")
    print(f"Actual End Date: {actual_end_date}")

    # Determine if the plan is achievable
    plan_achievable = actual_end_date <= latest_end_date
    print(f"Plan Achievable: {plan_achievable}")

    # Create a Matplotlib figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

    # Initialize the current time to the earliest start date
    current_time = earliest_start_date

    # Process each part number sequentially
    for i, row in schedule.iterrows():
        part_number = row['Part Number']
        num_batches = row['Number of batches required']
        print(f"Processing part number: {part_number}, Number of batches: {num_batches}")  # Debugging statement
        for batch in range(num_batches):
            start_time = current_time
            end_time = start_time + pd.Timedelta(hours=total_operations * multiplier / num_batches)
            ax.barh(part_number, (end_time - start_time).days, left=start_time, color='blue')
            current_time = end_time

    # Add color-coded borders based on feasibility
    border_color = "green" if plan_achievable else "red"
    ax.axvline(x=earliest_start_date, color=border_color, linewidth=3)
    ax.axvline(x=latest_end_date, color=border_color, linewidth=3)

    ax.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Part Number')
    ax.set_title('Production Schedule Gantt Chart')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    # Clear previous canvas if exists
    for widget in main_tab.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(widget, FigureCanvasTkAgg):
            widget.get_tk_widget().destroy()

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=main_tab)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    # Update summary
    summary_text = (f"Total Batches: {total_batches}\n"
                    f"Total Operations Time: {total_operations:.2f} hours\n"
                    f"Shift Length: {shift_length} hours\n"
                    f"Number of Operators: {num_operators}\n"
                    f"Number of Plating Vats: {num_vats}\n"
                    f"Total Shifts Required: {total_shifts_required:.2f}\n"
                    f"Plan Achievable: {'Yes' if plan_achievable else 'No'}\n"
                    f"Earliest Start Date: {earliest_start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}\n"
                    f"Actual End Date: {actual_end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}\n"
                    f"Latest End Date: {latest_end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")

    summary_label.config(text=summary_text)

    print("Load & Cap calculations completed.")
    print(summary_text)

# GUI Setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Production Scheduler")

# Create a tab control
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)

# Create the main tab
main_tab = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(main_tab, text="Main")

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

shift_length_var = tk.StringVar(value="0")
shift_length_label = tk.Label(main_tab, text="Shift Length (hours):")
shift_length_label.pack()
shift_length_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(main_tab, textvariable=shift_length_var, values=["0", "7.5", "15", "22.5"])
shift_length_dropdown.pack()

operators_var = tk.StringVar(value="0")
operators_label = tk.Label(main_tab, text="Number of Operators:")
operators_label.pack()
operators_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(main_tab, textvariable=operators_var, values=["0", "1", "2", "3"])
operators_dropdown.pack()

plating_vats_var = tk.StringVar(value="0")
plating_vats_label = tk.Label(main_tab, text="Number of Plating Vats:")
plating_vats_label.pack()
plating_vats_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(main_tab, textvariable=plating_vats_var, values=["0", "1", "2", "3"])
plating_vats_dropdown.pack()

upload_production_button = tk.Button(main_tab, text="Upload Production Plan", command=upload_production_file)
upload_production_button.pack()

upload_operational_button = tk.Button(main_tab, text="Upload Operational Data", command=upload_operational_file)
upload_operational_button.pack()

run_load_cap_button = tk.Button(main_tab, text="Run Load & Cap", command=run_load_and_cap)
run_load_cap_button.pack()

result_label = tk.Label(main_tab, text="")
result_label.pack()

completion_label = tk.Label(main_tab, text="")
completion_label.pack()

summary_label = tk.Label(main_tab, text="", justify="left")
summary_label.pack()

root.mainloop()


GUI front page control page
For the display update function I have tried putting in a loop so that when the dropdown values have changed the code iterates back to run the calculation again using the new constraints. I have tried coding to get the data files I upload to save in the memory for the calculations to run, I have tried manually uploading the data when I need to change the constraint to see if that updates the plot but none of these have worked thus far.
